# PHP - Echo everything after the second explosion array

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I've got a script that explodes an input, see below:

```
$message = explode(" ", $_GET['message']);
switch($message[0])
{
    case "/commands":
        echo "N/A";
    break;
    case "/mute":
        $player = $message[1];
        $time = $message[2]; // seconds
        $reason = $message[3];
        echo "Mute {$player} for {$time} seconds because {$reason}";
    break;
    default:
        echo "Invalid command";
    break;
}
```

I've stumbled into an issue, say the user was to use "/mute Steve 500 For being an idiot" - it would return to me `"Mute Steve for 500 seconds because For"` instead of providing me with the full reason, because I've used `$message[3]`, I'm asking you this:

How do I return everything after `$message[2]`?

Would I have to run a foreach loop, combining all the words together, or is there an easier method?

Sorry if it's hard to understand, I tried explaining the best I could, but it's a hard topic to explain.

Comment: did you run a `var_dump($message[3])` to see if it indeed contains anything? or better yet, run `var_dump($message)` to see everything

Comment: Where did the `/ban` come from?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the contents of my array, it's just I want to link everything after $message[2] together -- @RichardJPLeGuen; was a typo, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that easily with array_slice - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

In your case,

```
$reason = implode(' ', array_slice($message, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I return everything after `$message[2]`?

Use [`array_slice(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) like so:

```
$reason = join(' ', array_slice($message, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can format the `$message` in a slightly different way, it would be much easier. Rather than using spaces (and then exploding on them) if your message looked like this:

```
/ban||Steve||500||For being an idiot
```

Then you could explode on the double pipe like this:

```
$message = explode("||", $_GET['message']);
```

and the rest of your code would work as expected. If you cannot change the message being sent at all, it will get trickier and you will have to use a loop, a second implode or some regex to achieve this.